# create a sheet with cell value automatically and hyperlinked the cell value to it

Tags: vba, excel

I am using this VBA code to create new sheet for each cell value

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

        On Error Resume Next
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Then
            Set wsNew = Sheets(Target.Text)
            If wsNew Is Nothing Then Sheets.Add().Name = Target.Text
        End If
End Sub
```

it is working fine but the sheets are getting created before the main sheet I want them after and I want to link these cell values as hyperlink to their respective sheets.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  If Len(Target.Value) = 0 Then Exit Sub

  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Then
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsNew = Worksheets(Target.Text)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If wsNew Is Nothing Then
      With Worksheets.Add(after:=Me)
        .Name = Target.Text

        Target.Hyperlinks.Delete
        Target.Hyperlinks.Add Target, "", "'" & .Name & "'!" & .Range("A1").Address(False, False, xlA1)
      End With

      Me.Activate
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks GSerg. May I also put a link to main sheet on first cell of every sheet